# nvm tar: Unrecognized archive format

Tags: node.js, nvm

**Greetings Everybody!**

I had this problem while installing `node` via `nvm`

when i type:

`$ nvm install 5.5.0`

had this:

```
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.5.0/node-v5.5.0-darwin-x86.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
WARNING: checksums are currently disabled for node.js v4.0 and later
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Binary download failed, trying source.
######################################################################## 100.0%
Checksums empty
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Installing node v1.0 and greater from source is not currently supported
```

so main problem is there: `tar: Unrecognized archive format`
because(maybe) file format is: `tar.xz`

Answer (score 0):

After hours spending in google and git to solve this problem I didn't found the solution. Then started read `nvm` documentation and found force install option `-s`

It was helpful but not for all versions so now only installed `nvm install -s 0.12.9`

Comment: -s is from source. 
nvm install [-s] <version> Download and install a <version>, [-s] from source. Uses .nvmrc if available

Answer (score -1):

Installing node v1.0 and greater from source is not currently supported